# Irregular output in getting the week number of January

Tags: php, strtotime

Can someone explain why this is so?

```
<?php    
  echo date("W", strtotime("2015-01-01"))."<br>";  //returns 1
  echo date("W", strtotime("2014-01-01"))."<br>";  //returns 1
  echo date("W", strtotime("2016-01-01"))."<br>";  //returns 53
?>
```

When outputing the week number of the day in the month , result is incorrect for some cases. Here the output, week number is 1 which is true for first two cases but not in the third case.

Comment: Week 1 in 2016 starts Mon 4th.

Comment: Then how can I get the correct week number of that year.

Comment: Here  I want to return the week number as 1 since 01 Jan comes in the first week og the year.

Comment: The result is correct, because "W" gives ISO-8601 week number of year. Please read ISO-8601 definition of week

Comment: @tyro 1 Jan 2016 does not fall in the first week of the year 2016, but rather the last week of 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it outputs 53 and not 1 for `"2016-01-01"` is that it counts the first week of the year from the first monday of the year which in the year 2016 lies on the 4th of Jan ("2016-01-04").

> W ISO-8601 week number of year, weeks starting on Monday (added in PHP
> 4.1.0)    Example: 42 (the 42nd week in the year)

See full documentation for php date function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

As mentioned, **W   ISO-8601 week number of year** is the number that you get.

For more information on **W ISO-8601 week number of year** see below,

> An ISO week-numbering year (also called ISO year informally) has 52 or
> 53 full weeks. That is 364 or 371 days instead of the usual 365 or 366
> days. The extra week is referred to here as a leap week, although ISO
> 8601 does not use this term. Weeks start with Monday. The first week
> of a year is the week that contains the first Thursday of the year
> (and, hence, always contains 4 January). ISO week year numbering
> therefore slightly deviates from the Gregorian for some days close to
> 1 January.
>
> **Source: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)**

Answer (score 0):

*2016-01-01* belongs to the last week of year *2015*, as the week begins in that year, so the result is correct.